# Starting Videos with Buttons

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

So I'm building a program that plays a video depending on the GPIO button that is pressed on my Rapsberry Pi. However, once a video is played, OMX Player seems to dominate the focus and I can no longer switch videos while a video is playing. Any ideas anyone?

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time, sys, os

gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(23, gpio.IN)
gpio.setup(25, gpio.IN)


while True:
    if gpio.input(23):
        os.system('pkill omxplayer')
        os.system('omxplayer -r Shopping.mp4')

    if gpio.input(25):
        os.system('pkill omxplayer')
        os.system('omxplayer -r Dodgeball.mp4')
```

Comment: os.system will  wait for a return code. does `os.system('omxplayer -r Shopping.mp4 &')` make a difference?

Comment: I don't know. I'll give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Padraic. Write an answer so I can reward you.

Comment: Do you happen to know how one can keep the OMX Player window open even once the video has finished?

Comment: try `os.system('nohup omxplayer -r Shopping.mp4 &')`

Comment: Using subprocess would probably be a better option also. Popen  does not wait for a return code.

Comment: How do you know these arguments? Is there some documentation that I can read?

Comment: Is there an argument that fills the screen behind the fullscreen video?

Comment: `nohup` didn't work.

Comment: `&` just starts the task in the background, I would try using `subprocess.Popen` I have not set up my pi yet so I cannot test

Comment: `nohup` isn't working. Do you know how to keep the window open after playback? And how can I reduce the delay between the change in videos?

Comment: I will have a look tomorrow when I get my pi setup if you don't get an answer.

Comment: Have you figured out how to keep the video window open after it finishes?

Comment: How do you execute a video as soon as omxplayer finishes a video?